# Rails: Only update attribute when specified in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, checkbox, attributes

I have a form, in which users can add their birthday. Now currently, whenever someone submits this form, he will add a birthday, as the date input always has a value.

Is there a way I can add a checkbox - and only if it is checked, the birthday should be saved to the record? If the checkbox is not checked though, the current value for `birthday` should be removed.

```
= simple_form_for resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_url(resource_name) do |f|
    = f.input :another_field
    = f.input :birthday_set?, as: :boolean # or something else?
    = f.input :birthday
    = f.input :submit
```

Comment: This simplest way is to use before_save callback to track birthday_set param, and if it is false, set birthday to null, http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: @atomAltera Isn't there an easier way, because that means that I would also need an `attr_accessor`?

Comment: then you should solve that on controller level. Say you have create_params helper, which returns all fields, needed for model creation. You can make this check inside that helper

Comment: you can modify it at controller side if checkbox params is true then save else vice versa.

Comment: @johhue lets try the given solution below, and let me know for further guidance.

Comment: @Gabbar your solution has some problems as pointed out by SRack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the controller, you could do something like:

```
def create
  user = User.new
  user.birthday = params[:user][:birthday_set?] ? params[:user][:birthday] : nil
  params[:user].delete(:birthday, :birthday_set?)
  user.update_attributes(user_params)
  ...
end
```

And just remove the `:birthday` / `:birthday_set?` keys from the `permit` element of your params.

I'd look at moving `:birthday_set?` into a `form_tag` field so it sits outside of `params[:user]` and then you won't have to worry about clearing it from the params. If you're not storing it in the db, this makes more sense anyway.

This will avoid `unpermitted parameters` being thrown, and do exactly what you're after.

You could also look into disabling the `:birthday` field in the front end using js when the checkbox is toggled, but would still want to handle this regardless.

Personally, I'd go down @atomAltera's route and use an `attr_accessor` and `before_save`, but if you want to avoid that, this approach will work.